# How to append Enter key in string in angular Js

Tags: angularjs

when an input box get any value(String) the enter key will append in it.I have searched and found about the event key for enter which is 13.but i don't want to press enter for perform any activity.

Comment: you want to block the enter key in input ?

Comment: No i am using ng-submit in text box but don't want to press enter.?I want when text come i append a enter key and set it in text box.So my text will contain enter key in last and when this key will be seen by program it will fire an event according to ng-submit

Comment: The perhaps a text box is not the correct element? Look at the input element, that behaves more like what you're describing.

Comment: Is there any way to do all this action with input box?